# PointerPressed Path

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

This is a c# Metro Application.
I have a a ListView which has its own DataTemplate. When Clicked on a item in the ListView I do this to get the Id of the item.

```
var ItemId = ((Bettie)e.ClickedItem).Id;
```

Is it possible when Clicked/Pressed on a Path to do the same as with the ListView (ClickedItem)?

```
<Path Grid.Column="3" Data="M197.125,67.75 L202,58.375 L196.875,48.25 L251.125,48.125 L257,58.25 L251,67.875 z" Fill="#FF878F8B" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19.75" Margin="100.875,0.125,0,0" Grid.Row="3" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60.125" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "to do the same thing"? A Path has a `MouseLeftButtonUp` so yes you can capture a click.

Comment: A Path in metro app does not hava MouseLeftButtonUp as event.
When clicked on the Path i want to get the Id of the item.

Answer (score 0):

Use [the PointerPressed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerpressed.aspx) and the Name or Tag property instead of the Id.

```
private void Target_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var path = e.OriginalSource as Path;

    if(path != null)
    {
        //use path.Name or path.Tag
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using the PointerPressed event but I can't figure how to pass information about the item.

Comment: Cast the first parameter of the event handler to a Path or use the OriginalSource property of the PointerRoutedEventArgs. I added to my answer.